# sqlite - attach database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I followed some of the information I found on web about attaching a sqlite database for the purpose of copying a table from one sqlite db to another but I can't seem to get it working. I try to attach the database with this code:

```
DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath("WineDB.sqlite").toString();
SQLiteDatabase backupDatabase = backupDBHandler.getWritableDatabase();
backupDatabase.execSQL("ATTACH '" + DB_PATH + "' AS 'tempDb'");
```

Up until now it runs without an error.
Then I try to create a new table in the backup database by copying it from the tempDb:

```
sqlDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE my_Producent AS SELECT * FROM tempDb.my_Producent");
```

And it crashes with an error "no such table "tempDb.my_Producent" However I am sure the table exists in the database "WineDB.sqlite". I create it in onCreate method which is called before I attach the database to backupDatabase.

Thanks for any help
Cheers
user2302510

Comment: Single quotes around `tempDb` (in `ATTACH` statement) should not be there. Single quotes in SQLite are primarily for delimiting string literals. Statement should take the form `ATTACH ' drive/path/database_name' AS database_alias; `

Comment: What is the value of `DB_PATH`?

Comment: @CL. DB_PATH is path of database generated within the application where the databases are defaultly stored. In my case it is /data/data/com.app.name/databases/WineDB.sqlite

Comment: @PositiveLogic  I also tried it without the quotes. It does not make any difference.

Comment: Check if that file exists.

Comment: it does. I read from that database and everything works fine. I even checked it using: File file = new File(DB_PATH);
  return file.exists();

Comment: @Phil: I have added an answer. Check it out and let me know if it works for you. It runs great for me but I'm not 100% sure I haven't made any mistakes in the code when rewriting it from my project.

Answer (score 9):

@Phil. Yes I've got it working. However I don't really remember what the real issue was any more, so I'll just write a simplified sequence of steps I found in my code regarding copying from **firstDB** to **secondDB**. I execute the following operations in a `SQLiteOpenHelper` for the **firstDB**.

```
public class firstDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    SQLiteDatabase firstDB;
    //FIRST_DB_NAME is something like 'xxx1.sqlite'
    private static String FIRST_DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(FIRST_DB_NAME).toString();

    public void copyFromFirstToSecond(String secondDBName, int secondDBVersion) {
        //use the same context as for the firstDBHandler
        secondDBHandler = new SecondDBHandler(myContext, secondDBName, secondDBVersion);
        //here you create the secondDB if it does not exist yet
        try {
            secondDBHandler.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SQLiteDatabase secondDB = secondDBHandler.getWritableDatabase();

        //note there are single quotation marks around FIRST_DB_PATH but none around tempDb
        secondDB.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + FIRST_DB_PATH + "' AS tempDb");

        //here you start to copy the tables from firstDB first by checking if the table exists in secondDB (secondDB is now the 'main' one, tempDB is the attached firstDB
        secondDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main." + SECOND_DB_TABLE_NAME);

        //here you create a table as a copy of
        secondDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE main." + SECOND_DB_TABLE_NAME + " AS SELECT * FROM tempDb." + FIRST_DB_TABLE_NAME);

        //you can run the last two lines of code as many times as you need to copy all of the tables

        //after you have copied all of them, you need to detach the tempDB
        secondDB.execSQL("DETACH tempDb"); 
    }

}

public class SecondDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     //SECOND_DB_NAME is something like 'xxx2.sqlite'
    private static String SECOND_DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(SECOND_DB_NAME).toString();
     public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

          boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
          if (dbExist) {
              // do nothing - database already exist
          } else {
              //This calls onCreate method of this SecondDBHandler, where you 
              //create tables that you need initially (but not those which you
              //intent to copy from firstDB)
              this.getReadableDatabase();
              this.close();
          }
    }

    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        File file = new File(SECOND_DB_PATH);
        return file.exists();
    }    
}
```

then you just call:

```
FirstDBHandler firstDBHandler = new FirstDBHandler(getBaseContext(), FIRST_DB_NAME, FIRST_DB_VERSION);
firstDBHandler.getReadableDatabase();
firstDBHandler.copyFromFirstToSecond(SECOND_DB_NAME, SECOND_DB_VERSION);
```

Of course there are onCreate methods missing for both `SQLiteOpenHandler`'s but it is up to an application what is done there.

Hopefully the answer contains no errors. I have not tested it myself, just extracted a simplified version from my more complex code. If it has a few upvotes I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I figure out 2 ways to attach database.

1. do NOT "attach database" in `onCreate` and `onUpgrade`. It will fail because of "Cannot attach database within transaction".
   But you can attach database when you init database, then call `getReadableDatabase()` to make sure database will be created and upgraded.
   Then you can run the attach command.

   ```
   sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); // new SQLiteOpenHelper
   SQLiteDatabase db = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase(); // make sure the database will be created
   db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '/databases/xx.db' AS xx;"); // do attach database
   ```
2. But if you want to **do attach before onUpgrade()**, try this way:

endTransaction in onCreate(), then do attach, then beginTransaction

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.createTables(db); // do the normal onCreate() stuff

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();  // end transaction, so that you can do attach

        db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '/databases/xx.db' AS xx;"); // do attach database
        db.execSQL("DETACH DATABASE xx;"); // detach database

        db.beginTransaction(); // begin transation again
    }
```

**Reason:**

read the function of SQLiteOpenHelper.java, I find out that onCreate() and onUpgrade() are called together during transaction.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work, because calling "getReadableDatabase()", will automatically call "onUpgrade()". So how to execute the attach command BEFORE onUpgrade() been called?

Comment: hmmm... I guess sqlite don't want you to do attach before onUpgrade()...

Comment: I figure out the way to attach before onUpgrade(), see the updated answer~

Comment: Why you detach the database right after attach the database?

Comment: In my project, the attached database is useless later, so I detach it. You can do whatever suits your project.